# hazelcast 4.x open source security

Tags: java, security, hazelcast

I have upgraded open source hazelcast 3.x to 4.x, in hazelcast 4.x how security can be achieved, I mean group password has been removed from hazelcast 4.x.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, Hazelcast password was never really meant to provide any security. Please check [this](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/issues/14082) and [this](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/issues/11667#issuecomment-422477891) for details.

Hazelcast Security is an enterprise feature and, unfortunately, it can not be accessed in community version.